# Clojure's # lambda marco is not always the same as (fn)?

Tags: clojure

```
user> (map (fn [k] [k]) [1 2 3])
([1] [2] [3])
user> (map #([%1]) [1 2 3])
.... Error..
```

Why is the second example an error?

Comment: continuing your example, you can use (map #(vector %) [1 2 3]) for the same functionality.

Comment: or `(map vector [1 2 3])`

Answer (score 3):

The `#(<expr>)` reader macro wraps the `<expr>` in an extra set of parenthesis, so `#([%1])` expands to something equivalent to `(fn [%1] ([%1]))` and not `(fn [%1] [%1])`. So you are right. They are not entirely equivalent.

You can try the following in the REPL which will reveal the exact expansion:

```
user=> '#([%1])                   
(fn* [p1__862#] ([p1__862#]))
user=> '#(inc %1) 
(fn* [p1__865#] (inc p1__865#))
```